# How to make a delivery URL for a webhook in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I have a problem when I want make **WooCommerce hook**. It says:

> Make delivery URL

I do not know exactly how I made it! Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please, explain it better for us to identify the problem and solve it easier!

Comment: Where do you make the WooCommerce hook?

Comment: i want make hook in addres "wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=api&section=webhooks" when i want create this show error make delivery URL i want make delivery URL another host and i do not know exactly how i was (sorry for my English) @Atanas

Comment: Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: @Atanas i can , But I use persian version of woo....

Comment: Oh, no matter! Just get a screenshot for me to see, and add it to the question.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/mwqwak) 
خطا: آدرس تحویل نمی تواند برسد به:نشانی معتبر نیست.
in english 
Error: could not reach the delivery address: Address is not valid.

Comment: It seems the delivery url is incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure it's written correctly?

Comment: @Atanas Yes it says
Because the address is not made at all
I want to address to make it

Comment: @AtanasI do not have a delivery address
I want to make

Comment: @Atanas, please stop adding "Thank you" and "Any help will be much appreciated!" to your edits. **Check**: [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/1287812) and also [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/1287812)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the product, and then pass the URL of the product into the "Delivery URL" tab.

Comment: I do not have a delivery address
I want to make delivery address

Comment: Ok, make the delivery address and put your hooks in it.

Comment: I think he is asking for how to code that delivery URL, I'm looking for same thing.

Comment: Here is the answer in another stackoverflow question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185409/how-to-get-variable-for-a-customer-from-a-webhook-in-woocommerce